# Selecting items without duplicates in SQL, DISTINCT helping but not fully working

Tags: sql, distinct

I have a SQL request question where I have to "list the names of the publishers, and the number of books published, for publishers who have published 3 or more books". The book table has the publisher name [book (isbn, title, authorID, genre, pubYear, publisher, rrPrice, avgRating)] and the orderDetails has quantity [orderDetails (oNo, bookISBN, quantity)].

I have tried this SQL statement initially:

```
SELECT publisher, quantity
FROM book, orderDetails
WHERE ISBN IN (SELECT bookISBN 
               FROM orderDetails
               WHERE quantity > 3);
```

And it returned 425 rows, after adding `DISTINCT` to the select for publisher it returned 72 publishers, however this still contains many repeats with different quantity values, which I cannot understand why it is doing that. Apologies if this is a repeated question, however many of the questions i have read have been far more basic and I am new to SQL. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what has the orderDetail table to do with this? That is about how many books were bought - not published.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample  .. you actual result and the expected  result

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @PatrickArtner Yes you're correct, I have no idea where I was going with that in retrospect

Comment: @marc_s Thank you, very true. This is the way we were  taught by our lecturer and she told us to do it this way. Since I posted this question last year I've talked to employers and they say the course for the college I'm attending is fairly outdated and are still living the past in a lot of ways, I've really been seeing that this year haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order details table has nothing to do with the query you have put in because the question is not how much quantity ordered. For instance, book with isbn xyz may have quantity as more than 1 published by same author but it doesn't mean that the author has published more than one book in this case. Its how many books are published by each author not how many books ordered ( published by each author )
just

```
Select 
     publisher
    ,count(*) 
from book 
group by publisher 
having count(*) >= 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

As I commented: purchases have nothing to do with this. You look for how many books a publisher published - not how many he sold.

With

```
CREATE TABLE book
    ([isbn] varchar(10), [title] varchar(10), [authorID] int, [genre] varchar(7), 
     [pubYear] int, [publisher] varchar(11), [rrPrice] int, [avgRating] int)
;

INSERT INTO book
    ([isbn], [title], [authorID], [genre], [pubYear], [publisher], [rrPrice], [avgRating])
VALUES
    ('''a12345''', '''tata''', 1, '''ups''', 1998, '''tutut''', 23.4, 7.3),
    ('''a12345''', '''tata 2''', 1, '''ups''', 1999, '''tutut''', 23.4, 7.3),
    ('''a12345''', '''tata 3''', 1, '''ups''', 2000, '''tutut''', 23.4, 7.3),
    ('''a12345''', '''tata 4''', 1, '''ups''', 2001, '''tutut''', 23.4, 7.3),
    ('''a12345''', '''tata 5''', 1, '''ups''', 2002, '''tutut''', 23.4, 7.3),
    ('''a12345''', '''tata 6''', 1, '''ups''', 2003, '''tutut''', 23.4, 7.3),
    ('''a12345''', '''LK 6''', 2, '''ups''', 2003, '''lltutut''', 23.4, 7.3),
    ('''a12345''', '''LK 8''', 2, '''ups''', 2003, '''lltutut''', 23.4, 7.3)
```

and

```
SELECT publisher, count() 
from book   
group by publisher  
having count()>2
```

You should get

```
publisher    count()
'tutut'      6
```

Test: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vhRaL8BsuAa4juEnGjekez/0

Answer (score 1):

The question is almost already written in SQL, if you know how to read it.

```
select publisher,    -- list the names of the publishers,
       count(*)      -- and the number of books published,
from   book
group by publisher
having count(*) >= 3 -- who have published 3 or more books
```

The "trick" you're missing is `having`: it applies to the results of aggregate functions like `count` and `sum`.  By contrast, `where` filters the rows before aggregation.